# How to organize Array of objects via index node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have an array of objects that I want to reorganize but I can't figure out how to do it, I have tried using push and map to with no luck. Here is the current output and below that what I want the data to turn into.

```
0: {xSize: "4", xPrice: 1855}
1: {xSize: "4.5", xPrice: 1819}
2: {xSize: "5", xPrice: 2021}
3: {xSize: "5.5", xPrice: 2200}
4: {xSize: "6", xPrice: 1891}
5: {xSize: "6.5", xPrice: 1929}
6: {xSize: "7", xPrice: 1975}
7: {xSize: "7.5", xPrice: 1850}
8: {xSize: "8", xPrice: 1890}
9: {xSize: "8.5", xPrice: 2175}
10: {xSize: "9", xPrice: 2163}
11: {xSize: "9.5", xPrice: 2000}
12: {xSize: "10", xPrice: 2000}
13: {xSize: "10.5", xPrice: 2184}
14: {xSize: "11", xPrice: 2100}
15: {xSize: "11.5", xPrice: 2098}
16: {xSize: "12", xPrice: 2190}
17: {xSize: "12.5", xPrice: 2700}
18: {xSize: "13", xPrice: 2255}
19: {xSize: "14", xPrice: 1950}
20: {xSize: "15", xPrice: 3500}
21: {gSize: 4, gPrice: 1680}
22: {gSize: 4.5, gPrice: 1790}
23: {gSize: 5, gPrice: 1970}
24: {gSize: 5.5, gPrice: 2100}
25: {gSize: 6, gPrice: 1889}
26: {gSize: 6.5, gPrice: 1950}
27: {gSize: 7, gPrice: 1905}
28: {gSize: 7.5, gPrice: 1800}
29: {gSize: 8, gPrice: 1895}
30: {gSize: 8.5, gPrice: 2091}
31: {gSize: 9, gPrice: 2195}
32: {gSize: 9.5, gPrice: 2110}
33: {gSize: 10, gPrice: 2295}
```

I am looking to reformat the array of objects like so.

```
0: { xSize: 4, 
     xPrice: 1855, 
     gSize: 4, 
     gPrice: 1680},
1: { xSize: 4.5, 
     xPrice: 1819, 
     gSize: 4.5, 
     gPrice: 1790},
2: etc. etc.
```

Here is part of the script below, it takes in an input from frontend client and then searches through 2 external api's and is reworking the information into a new array.

```
function searchBrow(stockXurl) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(
      {
        url:
          "https://stockx.com/api/products/" +
          stockXurl +
          "?includes=market&currency=USD",
        method: "GET",
        headers: stockxGETHeaders,
      },

      function (err, res, body) {
        let json = JSON.parse(body);
        let shoeId = json.Product.title;
        let sku = json.Product.styleId;
        let release = json.Product.releaseDate;
        let parsedSizes = json.Product.children;

        let stockx = [];
        for (let a = 0; a < Object.keys(parsedSizes).length; a++) {
          let item = parsedSizes[Object.keys(parsedSizes)[a]];
          if (item.shoeSize.indexOf(".") == -1) {
            item.shoeSize = item.shoeSize.toString();
          }
          let sizing = item.shoeSize;
          let pricing = item.market.lowestAsk;
          stockx.push({
            xSize: sizing,
            xPrice: pricing,
          });
        }
        console.log(stockx);
        sendSkuGoat(sku, stockx).then((goatJoin) => {
          resolve(goatJoin);
        });
      }
    );
  });
}

function getGoatAsk(slug, photo, stockx) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(
      {
        method: "GET",
        url:
          "https://www.goat.com/api/v1/product_variants?productTemplateId=" +
          slug,
        headers: goatGETHeaders,
      },
      function (err, res, body) {
        json = JSON.parse(body);
        goatSizes = json[0].size;
        goatAsk = json[0].lowestPriceCents.amount;

        for (let j of json) {
          if (
            j.shoeCondition === "new_no_defects" &&
            j.boxCondition === "good_condition" &&
            j.size >= 4
          ) {
            const size = j.size;
            const amount = j.lowestPriceCents.amount * 0.01;

            stockx.push({ gSize: size, gPrice: amount });
          }
        }

        return resolve(stockx);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const groups = [{
    xSize: 4,
    xPrice: 1855
  },
  {
    xSize: 4.5,
    xPrice: 1819
  },
  {
    xSize: 5,
    xPrice: 2021
  },
  {
    xSize: 5.5,
    xPrice: 2200
  },
  {
    xSize: 6,
    xPrice: 1891
  },
  {
    xSize: 6.5,
    xPrice: 1929
  },
  {
    xSize: 7,
    xPrice: 1975
  },
  {
    xSize: 7.5,
    xPrice: 1850
  },
  {
    xSize: 0,
    xPrice: 1890
  },
  {
    xSize: 8.5,
    xPrice: 2175
  },
  {
    xSize: 9,
    xPrice: 2163
  },
  {
    xSize: 9.5,
    xPrice: 2000
  },
  {
    xSize: 10,
    xPrice: 2000
  },
  {
    xSize: 10.5,
    xPrice: 2184
  },
  {
    xSize: 11,
    xPrice: 2100
  },
  {
    xSize: 11.5,
    xPrice: 2098
  },
  {
    xSize: 12,
    xPrice: 2190
  },
  {
    xSize: 12.5,
    xPrice: 2700
  },
  {
    xSize: 13,
    xPrice: 2255
  },
  {
    xSize: 14,
    xPrice: 1950
  },
  {
    xSize: 15,
    xPrice: 3500
  },
  {
    gSize: 4,
    gPrice: 1680
  },
  {
    gSize: 4.5,
    gPrice: 1790
  },
  {
    gSize: 5,
    gPrice: 1970
  },
  {
    gSize: 5.5,
    gPrice: 2100
  },
  {
    gSize: 6,
    gPrice: 1889
  },
  {
    gSize: 6.5,
    gPrice: 1950
  },
  {
    gSize: 7,
    gPrice: 1905
  },
  {
    gSize: 7.5,
    gPrice: 1800
  },
  {
    gSize: 0,
    gPrice: 1895
  },
  {
    gSize: 8.5,
    gPrice: 2091
  },
  {
    gSize: 9,
    gPrice: 2195
  },
  {
    gSize: 9.5,
    gPrice: 2110
  },
  {
    gSize: 10,
    gPrice: 2295
  }
]
var groupedUp = [];
groups.forEach(x => {
  if (x.hasOwnProperty("xSize")) {
    let group = groupedUp.find(y => y.gSize == x.xSize)
    if (group) {
      group.xSize = x.xSize;
      group.xPrice = x.xPrice;
    } else {
      groupedUp.push(x);
    }

  }
  if (x.hasOwnProperty("gSize")) {
    let group = groupedUp.find(y => y.xSize == x.gSize)
    if (group) {
      group.gSize = x.gSize;
      group.gPrice = x.gPrice;
    } else {
      groupedUp.push(x);
    }
  }
})
console.log(groupedUp);
```

Comment: Your code fails if xSIze or gSize is 0. Use typeof or hasOwnProperty to check if a value is present.

Please do not use var (if not necesarry) in 2021 ;)
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274342/is-there-any-reason-to-use-the-var-keyword-in-es6

Comment: Thank you!! @AnasBzrAmma

Answer (score -1):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.

For your next question a hint: Show your code. We can't help if we don't know what you are doing.

There are several ways to solve your problem. I would suggest Array.prototype.reduce:

```
const allInOneArray = yourArray.reduce((reorderedArray, object) => {

    //shortcut to our sizes
    const xSize = object.xSize;
    const gSize = object.gSize;
    const xPrice = object.xPrice;
    const gPrice = object.gPrice;

    // declare the foundObject (important for scoping)
    let foundObject;

    // if our object has xSize => search for an object with the same gSize
    if (typeof xSize === 'number') {
        foundObject = reorderedArray.find(checkingObject => checkingObject.gSize === xSize);
        // we found one and add the other size
        if (foundObject) {
            foundObject.gSize = xSize;
            foundObject.gPrice = xPrice;
        }
    } else {
        // if we dont have the xSize given, check the gSize

        // if our object has gSize => search for an object with the same xSize
        if (typeof gSize === 'number') {
            foundObject = reorderedArray.find(checkingObject => checkingObject.xSize === gSize);
            // we found one and add the other size
            if (foundObject) {
                foundObject.xSize = gSize;
                foundObject.xPrice = gPrice;
            }
        }
    }
    // if we found no object
    if (!foundObject) {
        // we will create one (by copy the original object)
        reorderedArray.push({ ...object });
    }
    
    // return the reorderedArray to the next step
    return reorderedArray;
}, []);
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the warm welcome, sorry I didn't include code, I have updated that now, it takes an input from a frontend client so it cant really be run, I just included the two parts that are important for this array, the first function shown is gathering the data for the array stockx and pushing it in there, and the last function is doing the same as well and pushing the data to stockx. I could not get your code to work unfortunately, it would just output the same (42) array size. Thank you for taking a look and your help, it is much appreciated!